# Oracle - Why does the leading zero of a number disappear

Tags: oracle

I have data like 0.8 and 0.80. In my select query i got wrong data.
example
select 0.80 from dual;
select 0.8 from dual;

both are giving 0.8 but my expectation is to display o.80 when value is 0.80.
i found for all cases 0.90,0.70 .....
how to achieve this

Comment: That is a behavior of your client. Which client application do you use?

Comment: BTW that is a "trailing" zero.  A "leading" zero is at the left of a string.

Comment: There is no mathematical difference between `0.8` and `0.80`. Oracle will store them identically and any client will display them identically, with the same number of trailing zeroes, if the client is configured to display trailing zeroes. If you want to maintain the fiction that they are different you need to store and display the column as a string. But that would be madness.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is of type NUMBER (which it is in `select 0.8 from dual` for example) then 0.8 and 0.80 are indistinguishable - they are both stored internally the same way as the `dump` function shows:

```
with data (n) as 
( select 0.8 from dual
  union all
  select 0.80 from dual
  union all
  select 0.800000 from dual
)
select n, dump(n) from data;

0.8 Typ=2 Len=2: 192,81
0.8 Typ=2 Len=2: 192,81
0.8 Typ=2 Len=2: 192,81
```

So there is no way for Oracle to show them differently.  If you want a VARCHAR2 string rather than a NUMBER, use `select '0.8' from dual`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Ltrim(To_char(0.80, 'B999999999999999999990.99'), ' ') as bn from dual
```

Comment: in both cases it displaying 0.80 but in case of  select Ltrim(To_char(0.8, 'B999999999999999999990.99'), ' ') as bn from dual; it shoud display 0.8 only rt.

Answer (score 0):

`0.8`, `0.80` and `0.80000` are all the same number but they are formatted differently.

Oracle's internal representation of numbers does not store how you have formatted them when you input them so `0.8`, `0.80` and `0.8000` will all be held in the database memory as the number `0.8`.

You are returning a number and not a formatted string so Oracle will just return `0.8` and let the user interface (e.g. SQL/Plus) display that as it sees fit.

If you want the number with a specific format (i.e. always with two decimal places) then you will need to convert the number to its formatted string representation of that number:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( your_number, 'FM99999999990D00' ) FROM DUAL;
```

If you want the numbers formatted exactly as entered (with leading and/or trailing zeroes) then you will need to store those numbers as strings to maintain that formatting:

```
SELECT '0.8' FROM DUAL;
SELECT '0.80' FROM DUAL;
SELECT '00.8' FROM DUAL;
```